# Fix "Interpolation-only expressions are deprecated" warning in Terraform

Tags: terraform

I upgraded to Terraform v0.12.16 and now I am getting a lot of messages that look like this:

```
Warning: Interpolation-only expressions are deprecated

  on ../modules/test-notifier/test_notifier.tf line 27, in resource "aws_sns_topic_policy" "default":
  27:   arn    = "${aws_sns_topic.default.arn}"

Terraform 0.11 and earlier required all non-constant expressions to be
provided via interpolation syntax, but this pattern is now deprecated. To
silence this warning, remove the "${ sequence from the start and the }"
sequence from the end of this expression, leaving just the inner expression.

Template interpolation syntax is still used to construct strings from
expressions when the template includes multiple interpolation sequences or a
mixture of literal strings and interpolations. This deprecation applies only
to templates that consist entirely of a single interpolation sequence.
```

There are hundreds of these messages. Is there an automated way to fix them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This tool will automatically strip the beginning and ending quotes and braces for you, which fixes the warnings: https://github.com/apparentlymart/terraform-clean-syntax

```
go get github.com/apparentlymart/terraform-clean-syntax
terraform-clean-syntax .
```

Comment: getting:
```panic: didn't find any token of type TokenOBrack```

Answer (score 37):

```
  Warning: Interpolation-only expressions are deprecated

  on main.tf line 3, in provider "aws":
   3:   region  = "${var.region}"
```

I also got the above warning, which is due to the changed syntax for declaring variables in terraform.
See the example below -:

**Old syntax**-  region  = "${var.region}"   # you will get Interpolation-only warning

**New Synatx**-  region  = var.region        # no warning

Check the syntax and correct it using any code editor.

Comment: At current time this warning will be automatically fixed after `terraform fmt`

Answer (score 24):

Did you upgrade the code first?

Terraform 0.11 isn't compatible with 0.12, so you have to upgrade it first.

```
terraform init
terraform 0.12upgrade
```

If your Terraform code is calling other terraform modules, please make sure you have upgraded these terraform modules to 0.12 as well.

Comment: Yes, I upgraded the code. I was still getting the errors above.

Comment: jus to clarify, upgrading the modules means running this same 2 commands in the modules root like .terraform/modules/<module_name>

Answer (score 14):

Update interploations as below:

```
subscription_id = "${var.subscription_id}"
```

to

```
subscription_id = var.subscription_id
```

Answer (score 11):

[Terraform v14](https://www.hashicorp.com/blog/announcing-hashicorp-terraform-0-14-beta) `fmt` incorporated this. You can now get the `rc` binary and simply run `terraform fmt`.

Answer (score 6):

Martin Atkins's [terraform-clean-syntax](https://github.com/apparentlymart/terraform-clean-syntax) code can be used (thanks [Kevin Burke](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59038538/9799479) for clue)

I have shamelessly used it and packaged within docker container so it can be easily run on non linux_amd64 machines, e.g. MacOS:

https://github.com/NoLedgeTech/terraform-clean-syntax-docker

TL&DR (WARNING - this will update your tf files in place):

```
docker pull pniemiec/terraform-clean-syntax-docker
cd <DIRECTORY_WITH_TF_FILES>
terraform init
terraform plan    # This shows a lot of warnings
docker run --rm -v $(pwd):/code -t pniemiec/terraform-clean-syntax-docker
terraform plan    # This does not show a lot of warnings :sweat_smile:
```

Comment: This tool was helpful, but note that it doesn't uninterpolate values within arrays (e.g. subnet_ids). For that, I had to fall back to carefully applying a regex substitution: `"\$\{([^}"]+)\}"` It can't be applied blindly due to interpolation in here-documents.

Comment: For fish shell, `docker run --rm -v $(pwd):/code -t pniemiec/terraform-clean-syntax-docker`.

Answer (score 2):

Or you can use a simple sed:

```
sed -i 's/\"\${/\"/g;s/}\"/\"/g' main.tf
```

Comment: Worked really well. I used *.tf instead of main.tf, and it updated all the files

Comment: Actually, you're replacing strings with `"`. Instead, you want it replaced with nothing: `sed -i 's/\"\${//g;s/}\"//g' *tf`.

Your result turns `private_key = "${file("ssh_key")}"` into `private_key = "file("ssh_key")"`, which is invalid. You want the result to be `private_key = file("ssh_key")`

Answer (score 2):

The solution in already in the log output: `... remove the "${ sequence from the start and the }" ...`

Answer (score 1):

I used notepad++ to remove that interpolation syntax.

**regex:**

```
^(.*)\${(.*)}
```

**replace_with:**

```
\1\2
```

Comment: In VScode I used `"\$\{([^$]*)\}"` and replaced with `$1`

Answer (score 1):

You used =>  arn "${aws_sns_topic.default.arn}"

Try to use without interpolation, like: arn = aws_sns_topic.default.arn