# terraform plan error "features": required field is not set

Tags: terraform, infrastructure-as-code

`terraform init` initialize successfully, below is my main.tf

```
############################################################################
# VARIABLES
#############################################################################

variable "resource_group_name" {
  type  = string
}

variable "location" {
  type    = string
  default = "eastus"
}


variable "vnet_cidr_range" {
  type    = string
  default = "10.0.0.0/16"
}

variable "subnet_prefixes" {
  type    = list(string)
  default = ["10.0.0.0/24", "10.0.1.0/24"]
}

variable "subnet_names" {
  type    = list(string)
  default = ["web", "database"]
}

#############################################################################
# PROVIDERS
#############################################################################

provider "azurerm" {

}

#############################################################################
# RESOURCES
#############################################################################

module "vnet-main" {
  source              = "Azure/vnet/azurerm"
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  location            = var.location
  vnet_name           = var.resource_group_name
  address_space       = var.vnet_cidr_range
  subnet_prefixes     = var.subnet_prefixes
  subnet_names        = var.subnet_names
  nsg_ids             = {}

  tags = {
    environment = "dev"
    costcenter  = "it"

  }
}

#############################################################################
# OUTPUTS
#############################################################################

output "vnet_id" {
  value = module.vnet-main.vnet_id
}
```

When I run `terraform plan -var resource_group_name=vnet-main -out vnet.tfplan`
getting below warnings:

> Warning: Interpolation-only expressions are deprecated
>
> on
>   .terraform/modules/vnet-main/Azure-terraform-azurerm-vnet-e0b9155/main.tf
>   line 3, in resource "azurerm_resource_group" "vnet":    3:   name
>   = "${var.resource_group_name}"
>
> Warning: Quoted type constraints are deprecated
>
> on
>   .terraform/modules/vnet-main/Azure-terraform-azurerm-vnet-e0b9155/variables.tf
>   line 39, in variable "nsg_ids":   39:   type        = "map"

finally getting below error:

> Error: "features": required field is not set

As per suggestion mentioned in below stackoverflow article if I run upgrade command (`terraform 0.12upgrade`) to upgrade to 0.12 getting below error:

[Fix "Interpolation-only expressions are deprecated" warning in Terraform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59038537/fix-interpolation-only-expressions-are-deprecated-warning-in-terraform)

> Error: Syntax error in configuration file
>
> on main.tf line 6, in variable "resource_group_name":    6:   type 
>   = string
>
> Error while parsing: At 6:11: Unknown token: 6:11 IDENT string

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hey you have to specify `features` block like following to fix the issue

```
provider "azurerm" {
  version = "=2.4.0"
  features {}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There seem to be a few issues here, but not necessarily a direct question, so I'll take a shot at each one. Note you don't NEED to fix warnings, only errors, though fixing both is recommended.

> Warning: Interpolation-only expressions are deprecated

In newer versions of terraform, resource attributes should be passed directly rather than wrapping them in interpolation.

So do

```
resource "my_resource" "name" {
  some_attr = var.some_value
}
```

instead of

```
resource "my_resource" "name" {
  some_attr = "${var.some_value}"
}
```

unless string interpolation is actually necessary to build a string from other values.

> Warning: Quoted type constraints are deprecated
>
> on .terraform/modules/vnet-main/Azure-terraform-azurerm-vnet-e0b9155/variables.tf line 39, in variable "nsg_ids": 39: type = "map"

It looks like the module that you're depending on is not forwards-compatible with the version of terraform you're using (at least from a "Warning" perspective).

This specific complaint is because it uses quotes around the `map` type (e.g. `"map"` rather than just `map`). This can be seen it the [module's source](https://github.com/Azure/terraform-azurerm-vnet/blob/master/variables.tf#L39).

Your only real option here is to fork the module and fix the warnings/upgrade or open a PR and hope the maintainers merge (though it looks like that repo hasn't had activity for 2 years).

> Error: "features": required field is not set

This is the *real* error I think you are probably looking to fix. The answer is simply that your provider is missing the [required `features` block](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/index.html#features) (this can even be empty).

So using the following should fix this error

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}
```

> Error: Syntax error in configuration file
>
> on main.tf line 6, in variable "resource_group_name": 6: type = string
>
> Error while parsing: At 6:11: Unknown token: 6:11 IDENT string

I believe that the issue here is that the upgrade command expects the terraform that's being upgrade to be valid `0.11` code. And in `0.11`, the `type` fields are expected to have `string` values (e.g. `"map"`, `"string"`, etc...).